# Addthis + pinterest : strange behaviors

Tags: image, pinterest, addthis

I try to use addthis on my website, and to force the pinterest button to share only the image i want.

And there is 2 problems :

- Addthis try to share all the image of the website, not the one i gave to him
- some image are not listed, despite he try to share all images

Here is a simple code to explain better (sorry i cant put it on js fiddle) :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Wikipedia-logo-v2-fr.png" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- images shared -->   
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Wikipedia-logo-v2-fr.png" title="test1" />
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png" title="test2" />

  <!-- images not shared (why ?) -->
  <img src="http://spamty.eu/img/famfamfam/gb.png" title="test3" />


  <div class="shareaddthis">
      <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
      <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
        <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit" pi:pinit:media="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/Wikipedia-logo-v2-fr.png"></a>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-553e0a160661a362"></script>
      <!-- AddThis Button END -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I followed the [addthis documentation](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381237-third-party-buttons#pinterest-pinit), and i tried the solution of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599747/addthis-pinterest-widget-is-offereing-images-i-dont-want-to-offer-such-as-nav) (using the `addthis_config`), it changes nothing.

Someone has a solution ?

Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**
I resolved the problem by using the pinterest button without addthis, with this code :

```
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/
        ?url= websiteurl
        &media= imageurl
        &description= imagedescr"
        data-pin-do="buttonPin"
        data-pin-config="beside">
  <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

I put it into the addthis container and it work fine.

And for the image not shared in my example, it's because the image is too small (min 200x100px or 100x200px). But i had other issues where image was not recognised by pinterest, even if they was large enough.