# Use pinterest save button on specific id/class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pinterest

Is there anyway to configure the pinterest save button to appear only in the images with an specific class/id or multiple classes and ids?

Can it be done using the default embed code or should I use the API?

```
<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-tall="true" data-pin-lang="en" data-pin-save="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

In other words, the code currently appears over every single image of the website, I would like it to appear only on the images that have an specific class or id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `data-pin-nopin` to the images you dont want to pin

```
<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-tall="true" data-pin-lang="en" data-pin-save="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
<img data-pin-nopin src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
```

From the [docs](https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/)

> data-pin-nopin
>
> The image can't be saved, and hover buttons won't appear on the image.
> This attribute is applied to individual images on your page.

Comment: CAn I add it to a div instead?

Comment: From the looks of it no

Comment: But if you have the class already set on everything im sure you can programmatically add the nopin via jquery

Comment: Yep, I do have one.

Comment: What about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599747/addthis-pinterest-widget-is-offereing-images-i-dont-want-to-offer-such-as-nav

Comment: It's your question haha

Comment: `data-pin-nopin` works fine when placed on the image

Comment: That's meant for another question:)

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery I just did the following since I set the following pinterest attribute on all the images I wanted the save button to show up on...

```
     //remove Pinterest save button for all images
     $("img").attr("data-pin-no-hover", true);
     //add it back to images for which I've defined the pinterest image
     $("img[data-pin-media]").removeAttr("data-pin-no-hover");
```